# Set Celery Beat task priority with `add_periodic_task()`

Tags: celery, celerybeat

I've searched extensively, but cannot find anything on this.

Is it possible to set a celery task priority for a celery beat task, when using `add_periodic_task()` something like:

```py
sender.add_periodic_task(
    crontab(minute="*/5"),
    self_monitor_health_checks,
    priority=3,
)
```

Thanks for your help and input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the above does work, despite it being undocumented. You can set a priority like this:

```py
sender.add_periodic_task(
    crontab(minute="*/5"),
    self_monitor_health_checks,
    priority=3,
)
```